# Is there any example for ejabberd mod_carboncopy?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to add in Mod_carboncopy for Ejabberd, but not sure how to configure it in the web admin panel. Or would i have to config it in the config.yml instead??

I am not sure what is the expected behavior or how to config it, so i need some point to see where to start from.

1.) If i can config it in the web admin panel in the options for mod_carboncopy?

2.) Do i have to config it in config.yml

3.) After i config it do i have to reboot the server??

4.) After that is set up. Would i see the copy straight away in a RAW input for device 2, if device 1 sends out a message??

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished it. It is actually quite simple.

All you have to do is make sure your ejabberd is 15.03 or later, which has the carboncopy on by default. Then if you are using strophe, it is very simple to write the plugin. All you have to do is to enable it through IQ. Then everythings good to go!!